# Filter text out of barcode while scanning physical barcodes

Tags: excel, ms-access, barcode, scanning

I have a physical barcode on my packet. I need to filter out a text that says `"CustID: "` the whole barcode reads `"CustID: 123456798"`.

My sheet contains `"123456798"` and I need the two to match. I have about 40000 barcodes so removing the `"CustID: "` while scanning each barcode simultaneously would work well and be faster for me.

I am using MS Access while scanning barcodes in the control source box I've tried typing `=Replace("","CustID: ","")` to remove the text but returns nothing when I try to scan the barcodes.

I would like the barcode to say `"123456789"` and not `"CustID: 123456798"` while filtering out each text before the barcode reads in my numbers.

My resolution was to put

```vb
Dim lngCurBarCode1 As Long

If Me.txtRec.Text <> "" Then

    Me!txtRec.SetFocus
    If Me!txtRec.Text Like "RecID: *" Then
       Me!txtRec = Replace(Me!txtRec.Text, "RecID: ", "")
    End If
    lngCurBarCode1 = Me.txtRec.Text

End If
```

where textRec is the textbox

Comment: That's not how `REPLACE` works. try `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"CustID: ","")` Where `A1` is the cell with the current barcode number

Comment: I get a #NAME? when I use Substitute. I am using a textbox to scan my barcodes into which is why I want to remove the text.

Comment: Where does Excel feature in this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding the following event procedure to either the `After Update` or `On Change` events of your MS Access textbox:

```vb
Private Sub YourTextbox_AfterUpdate()
    If YourTextbox Like "CustID: *" Then
        YourTextbox = Replace(YourTextbox, "CustID: ", "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Change `YourTextbox` to the name of your textbox.

Comment: It still contains the text string. I added it to both the on change and after update. I've tried filtering out from scanner program...but didn't work either. I assume filtering it from access would be easier. Also I added Me. in front to.

Comment: It works now I needed to put my text in a different section. I'll post answer in my question

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution, so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Small flaw:`TextBox_Change`Event has to use`TextBox.Text`as`TextBox.Value`is not refreshed at`TextBox_Change`.

Answer (score 0):

With office 365, and as a much more generic process (i.e. multiple text portions or text which alters can all be caught); this can now easily be done with a formula.

```
=LET(arr, VSTACK(CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65)),{" ";":"}), REDUCE(A1, arr, LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,""))))
```

> an array of A-Z is created and appended to an array of " " and ":"

> The array values are then sequentially replaced by null text to leave the numeric components from the reference cell.

If you wanted to remove all the numbers you could do something similar:

```
=REDUCE(A1, SEQUENCE(10,,0), LAMBDA(a,b, SUBSTITUTE(a, b, "")))
```